# Can not publish sql server code to source control with SSDT because of CDC

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2008-r2, publish, sql-server-data-tools, cdc

I am trying to publish database source code to source control (TFS) with SSDT (Sql server 2008R2, SSDT VS 2010). The problem is that it generates the code even before Pre-script with the following script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CHANGE_TRACKING = OFF 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END


GO
```

It fails with following message:

> (64,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 22115, Level 16,
>
> State 1, Line 5 Change tracking is enabled for one or more tables in
>   database 'MyDb'. Disable change  tracking on each table before
>   disabling it for the database. Use the  sys.change_tracking_tables
>   catalog view to obtain a list of tables for which change tracking  is
>   enabled.

The only workaround I found is to disable change tracking manually and enable it in pre-script, but this solution is not very good...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution. I just needed to mark checkbox "Change tracking" in the Project Settings -> Database Settings -> Operational